# What does "public acceptance" here mean?

Tags: meaning, literature

What does "public acceptance" here mean?

Does it allude to their confession to spiritual interpretation before the public?

> “We have had experience in these latter days of mediums giving
> themselves up in the same unreserved way to scientific investigation
> and being betrayed by the investigators, who had not the moral courage
> to admit those results which would have entailed their own **public
> acceptance** of the spiritual interpretation.”

*[The History of Spiritualism](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html#chap11)*   By A.C Doyle
<sub>XI.THE RESEARCHES OF SIR WILLIAM CROOKES (1870-1874)</sub>

Comment: Please give us the source of the passage. You should always say where it comes from, as it may affect the answer.

Comment: Doubtless ACD again. I think it (in the flowery style of the day) is supposed to mean that some investigators only reported the failures or the frauds of mediums. Had they reported the successes, they would have been (in the view of ACD) making a public acknowledgement that spiritualism was real and true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means they would give their assent to the spiritual interpretation, and let this fact be known in the public domain rather than just hold it as a private thought.

Comment: thanks for your straightforward answer